# Console app using more threads than it should

Tags: c#, windows

Using the Resource Monitor that comes with Windows 8, I can see that my very simple console app is using 5 threads. I'm aware of that one of those are the main thread, and another one is possibly the GC thread, but I've got no idea what the last 3 are for.

**Code:**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("TEST");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are infrastructure threads. Don't worry about them; you can't do anything about them, and they aren't hurting you - they certainly won't be chomping CPU. Leave well alone.

Comment: If @MarcGravell says then it definately has to be true!! :)

Comment: Not quite sure what to make of ^^^^^^

Comment: It was in your honor Mr. Marc.. Not in any another sense.